# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 3948 (42000): Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides

Tags: mysql, python

I am working on a python project with MySQL connectivity. I have MySQL as a shell, i.e.,I need to use `mysqlsh` command in the Terminal to use MySQL(I am using MacOS Mojave 10.14.6). I needed to use a *csv file* to store data taken from user and then transfer it to a MySQL database. After doing some research, I found the best way to do it was by giving the`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command to `my_c.execute()`('*my_c*' is the cursor I defined to use for Python-MySQL connectivity) in Python. However when I run the command:
`my_c.execute('LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \"/test1\Desktop/Python/Practice/body.csv\" INTO TABLE POQ COLUMNS TERMINATED BY \",\" ESCAPED BY \'"\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'IGNORE 1 LINES')`

I get the following errors:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 3948 (42000): Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.

Here is a screenshot of the code:

[image: Password has been removed]

As both the files(python and the source file) are in the same directory, I tried removing the full path of the file, and just writing the file name; but that didn't work either.

#The password has been removed.

Here is the screenshot of the error output:

[image]

I tried researching the errors, and many suggested to use the command `show global variables like 'local_infile';` and `set global local_infile=true;` in MySQL. Sure the value changed from `NULL` to `ON`. But there was still no difference.

[image]

#Some solutions suggested to make changes to the *'my.cnf'* file. Bit when I tried to find it, I found that it doesn't exist.
#Some suggested to make changes to *secure-file-priv* in the file *file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf*. But this file was also not found.

Can someone pls tell what is wrong and how to fix it? Pls give step-by-step solution as I am not very good with the in-depth technical details of it.

Other information:

1. OS: MacOS Mojave(10.14.6)
2. Python version: 3.9.2
3. MySQL shell version: 8.0.23

If you need other information, do tell.

Comment: This behaviour is described in the documentation; have you tried the approach suggested therein?

Comment: @mustaccio No i did not. As I said earlier, though I am very familiar with these things, however their working at the basic level, and the its documentation is very technical for me.

Comment: `LOAD DATA` has several weird rules having to do with directory and file permission, especially when replicating.  Study the manual carefully.

Comment: The value of `local_infile` must be set to ON in both server side (must be set in my.ini in [mysqld] section or by according statement, you have checked it) and client side (must be set in my.ini in [client] section or in the client software options - and you have not checked this).

Comment: @Akina While researching to resolve the error, I did come across this solution. However the problems starts again, the file doesn't appear to exist. I have no idea what happened to it, because I never messed with such files.

Comment: *the file doesn't appear to exist* You use incorrect slash between `test1` and `Desktop`. Replace witn `/`. You use incorrect `.. LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\' ..` - `\n` is assumed to be quoted `n` char by python. Must be `LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'` - 2 slashes will be treated as quoted slash by python, mySQL will receive `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this statement: `allow_local_infile=True` in the line `mydb=mysql.connect(user='root', host='localhost', passwd='')` fixed it.

Finally it is:
`mydb = mysql.connect(user='root', host='localhost', passwd='', allow_local_infile=True)`